# Pass BoxSelectTool cb_data selection to Python code in Bokeh Server

Tags: python, bokeh

I have a bokeh plot where I need the user to interactively select a certain x-range. With this selection, I need to execute complex Python code - a CustomJS callback is not an option.

The `BoxSelectTool` seems perfect for this - from the look and feel of it, it is exactly what I need (See screenshot below).

According to the documentation, after finishing a selection, a custom callback can be invoked that tells me the selection range *cb_data*. However, I cannot find a way to pass that to a Python function - it looks like I can only add a CustomJS callback as callback.

What is the preferred way of passing the selection to custom Python code in Bokeh server? Is there any other tool that works like the `BoxSelectTool`?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to emulate the behaviour by activating the BoxSelectTool, ignoring it, and instead reading the raw data generated by the events (as documented [here](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/events.html#bokeh.events.PanEnd) ):

```
fig_speeds.add_tools(BoxSelectTool(dimensions="width"))

def cb_on_pan_start(event):
  print("start{} _ ".format(event.x))
fig_speeds.on_event(PanStart, cb_on_pan_start)

def cb_on_pan_end(event):
  print("{} ".format(event.x))
fig_speeds.on_event(PanEnd, cb_on_pan_end)
```

Obviously, I substituted the print statements with my actual event code, but you get the idea.